# Convert Object-C to SWIFT textKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uifontdescriptor

The following code was used in my app to change the state for text in a textview between bold and italic.  I have been trying to re-write it in Swift but I keep getting compile errors.  Below is the objective-C version that was provided to my in an online tutorial.  Following that is my new swift version up-to the point that the method is crashing.
I would apprecaite any help that might help me understand why the compiler is complaining so much.

```
-(void)addOrRemoveFontTraitWithName:(NSString *)traitName andValue:(uint32_t)traitValue{
NSRange selectedRange = [_field2 selectedRange];


NSDictionary *currentAttributesDict = [_field2.textStorage attributesAtIndex:selectedRange.location
                                                                effectiveRange:nil];


UIFont *currentFont = [currentAttributesDict objectForKey:NSFontAttributeName];
UIColor *currentColor = [currentAttributesDict objectForKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
UIColor *currentBGColor = [currentAttributesDict objectForKey:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName];
UIFont *currentUnderlinedText = [currentAttributesDict objectForKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *currentparagraphStyle = [currentAttributesDict objectForKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];    //receive and set new font name



UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [currentFont fontDescriptor];


NSString *fontNameAttribute = [[fontDescriptor fontAttributes] objectForKey:UIFontDescriptorNameAttribute];
UIFontDescriptor *changedFontDescriptor;

if ([fontNameAttribute rangeOfString:traitName].location == NSNotFound) {


    uint32_t existingTraitsWithNewTrait = [fontDescriptor symbolicTraits] | traitValue;
    changedFontDescriptor = [fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:existingTraitsWithNewTrait];

}
else{
    uint32_t existingTraitsWithoutTrait = [fontDescriptor symbolicTraits] & ~traitValue;
    changedFontDescriptor = [fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:existingTraitsWithoutTrait];

}
UIFont *updatedFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:changedFontDescriptor size:0.0];

//create new NSDict. called dict.
NSMutableDictionary *dict;
//call below function that returns an NSMutableDict. and places value to dict.
dict = [self checkSlectedAttributes:updatedFont SelFontColor:currentColor SelFontBGColor:currentBGColor SelunderLineState:currentUnderlinedText paragraphStyle:currentparagraphStyle];
```

// NSLog(@"the dict is: %@", dict);

```
[_field2.textStorage beginEditing];
[_field2.textStorage setAttributes:dict range:selectedRange];
[_field2.textStorage endEditing];
```

}

SWIFT CODE:
    func addOrRemoveFontTraitWithName(traitName: String!, andValue traitValue: UInt32) {

```
    let selectedRange : NSRange = self.textView.selectedRange

    var currentAttributesDict : NSDictionary = textView.textStorage.attributesAtIndex(selectedRange.location, effectiveRange: nil)

    var currentFont : UIFont = currentAttributesDict .objectForKey(NSFontAttributeName) as UIFont

    var currentColor : UIColor = currentAttributesDict.objectForKey(NSForegroundColorAttributeName) as UIColor
    var currentBGColor : UIColor = currentAttributesDict.objectForKey(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName) as UIColor
    var currentUnderLinedText : UIFont = currentAttributesDict.objectForKey(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName) as UIFont
    var currentparagraphStyle : NSMutableParagraphStyle = currentAttributesDict.objectForKey(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName) as NSMutableParagraphStyle

    var fontDescriptor : UIFontDescriptor = currentFont.fontDescriptor()
    var fontNameAttribute : NSString = fontDescriptor.objectForKey(UIFontDescriptorNameAttribute) as NSString
    var changedFontDescriptor : UIFontDescriptor

    if (fontNameAttribute.rangeOfString(traitName).location == NSNotFound){
       var existingTraitsWithNewTrait : UInt32 = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits | traitValue
        changedFontDescriptor = fontDescriptor.fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(existingTraitsWithNewTrait)
    }else{

        var existingTraitsWithNewTrait : UInt32 = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits & ~traitValue
        changedFontDescriptor = fontDescriptor.fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(existingTraitsWithNewTrait)
    }
```

}

Comment: Which part are you struggling with specifically?

Comment: everything in the if statment.  when I try to write this if statment using swift I get complaings about the | and the & simbles and there is a conversion error for the uint32_t  to fontDescriptor

Comment: I'd recommend posting your current swift code so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I am running into problems when I try to write the following statement:  var existingTraitsWithNewTrait = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits | traitValue  , The error I am getting is: cannot invoke '|' with an argument list of type '(UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits, UInt32)'"  I hope this helps with my explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the docs for `UIFontDescriptor`'s "Symbolic Font Traits"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits), the `UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits` are defined with type `uint32_t` in Objective-C, but not in Swift.

Try changing your code to the following:

```
if fontNameAttribute.rangeOfString(traitName).location == NSNotFound {
    let existingTraitsWithNewTrait : UInt32 = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.rawValue | traitValue
    changedFontDescriptor = fontDescriptor.fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits(rawValue: existingTraitsWithNewTrait))
} else {
    let existingTraitsWithNewTrait : UInt32 = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.rawValue & traitValue
    changedFontDescriptor = fontDescriptor.fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits(rawValue: existingTraitsWithNewTrait))
}
```

And if you still need to access the `UInt32` value of `UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits` you can request the raw value:

```
var existingTraitsWithNewTraitUInt32:UInt32 = existingTraitsWithNewTrait.rawValue
```

Comment: Your first example is pretty much what I am already trying, but the rawValue looks promising. When I used .rawValue there first block of code in the if statement works but the second line complains that UInt32 is not convertible to UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits.

Comment: @EdwardG That first bit of code is different from the code you posted. Have you actually tried it? Because it works for me... You don't need to convert anything to a UInt32 in your current code.

Comment: Yes, I am getting the same error. being an amateur programmer, I am trying to convert the code from objective-C to Swift because it seems the most straight forward way to do it, but perhaps there is a different or easier way to switch between bold and italic in SWIFT.  One thing that I don't get is the use of bitwise operators, I don't understand their use and what the '|'(or) and '&'(and) symbols are there for.

Comment: @EdwardG I'm not getting an error with that code so your code must be different in some way.

Comment: Swift Compiler Error:  cannot invoke '|' with an argument list of type '(UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits, UInt32)

Comment: @EdwardG And I'm telling you... I'm not getting that same error. Although its declaration is not in the code you posted, my guess is that your traitValue variable is a UInt32 when it should be a UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits. *Everything* that was of type UInt32 should be of type UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits in Swift.

Comment: That was it, I changed the type to UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits and the errors went away.  Thank you so much for your help.